# scalafx + intellij : NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/shape/CullFace

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalafx

I am blocked while trying to create a javafx scala project.I created a scala project in intellij idea 13 (the ast one), then I added manuelly the jar of scalafx ("scalafx_2.10-8.0.0-M1.jar") and copied this little program :

```
object World extends JFXApp {
stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Hello World"
    width = 600
    height = 450
    scene = new Scene {
        fill = Color.LIGHTGREEN
        content = Set(new Rectangle {
            x = 25
            y = 40
            width = 100
            height = 100
            //fill <== when(hover) then Color.GREEN otherwise Color.RED
        })
    }
}
}
```

but unfortunately I get this error message:

> Exception in Application start method
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:399)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/shape/CullFace
>       at scalafx.Includes$.(Includes.scala:55)

it seems the problem is linked with javafx, which I ignored since it is normally packed with java7...
can you tell me what I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scalafx_2.10-8.0.0` is intended for Java 8. If you need to work with Java 7 get `scalafx_2.10-1.0.0`.

In Java 7, JavaFX is not in classpath by default, so you may need to add it, though IntelliJ adds it.

Comment: ok thanks, but now I have an other problem, please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520122/unknown-by-intellij-while-using-scalafx .