# '<==' unknown by intellij while using scalafx

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, javafx, scalafx

A sign is not recognized by intellij : "<==", in a scala program using scalafx.

The scalafx version of the jar is 2.10:1.0.0-M5.
the program is this:

```
object launcher extends JFXApp {

stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Hello Stage"
    width = 600
    height = 450
    scene = new Scene {
        fill = Color.LIGHTGREEN
        content = new Rectangle {
            x = 25
            y = 40
            width = 100
            height = 100
            fill <== when (hover) choose Color.GREEN otherwise Color.RED
        }
    }
}

}
```

do you know where does the error comes from?(the intellij version is the last one : v13).java version is 1.7.0 x64 for mac, and scala version is 2.10.0. 
Please note thet "choose" & "otherwise" are also not recognized.
thanks

Comment: I had this issue and fixed it by adding the javafx jar file to my java SDK paths in the module settings.  The specific jar file I added was java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the imports for ScalaFX itself. See the full listing in the Wiki: https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/wiki/GettingStarted

(Yes, the documentation should include these. I encountered similar problems at the start.)

Comment: well, I don't think: I use intellij idea but I have java 7 as a dependency for the project, the scalafx jar is installed (v1.0.0) & jfxrt.jar is also here (see this picture :http://fr.tinypic.com/r/rh25o7/5).I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
import scalafx.Includes._
```

in your imports.